# SonarQube on Windows Vs Linux

Tags: sonarqube

I am wondering if there are any differences or caveats using SonarQube on Windows vs Linux?
Also, if there are any caveats using a MSSQL database vs MySQL for SonarQube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the [Prerequisites and Overview](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/), it mentions as the following: -

> Prerequisite
>
> The only prerequisite for running SonarQube is to have Java (Oracle JRE 11 or OpenJDK 11) installed on your machine.

The `SonarQube` server requires `Java 11` and provides the supporting database as `PostgreSQL`, `Microsoft SQL Server` and `Oracle` (*Note: there is no `MySQL`*). Furthermore there also is a [`Docker` image](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/#header-4) as well.

IMHO, we are free to choose the environment, e.g. OS and Database, which we are familiar and feel comfortable, especially to have a support from our system admin for making it moving faster.

Anyhow the hardware sizing is one significant, please consult the [Hardware Requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/#header-2) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/hardware-recommendations/) for further information.